# Setting AWS EC2 instance hostname using CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I know that I can set the name `key/tag` pair in a launch config in `cloudformation` template like below

```
"SaltMasterGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "DesiredCapacity": "1",
        "LaunchConfigurationName": { "Ref": "SaltMasterLaunchConfig" },
        "Tags" : [ {
         "Key" : "Name",
         "Value" : "saltmaster.lab.example.com",
         "PropagateAtLaunch" : "true"}
       ]
      }
    }
```

However can I set the private `hostname` using a CFN template?  As you can see I am using salt so I am prepared to set the names using salt, but I was hoping for a CFN solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use userdata to set the host name with

```
sudo hostname myhost
echo myhost > /etc/hostname
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: Any thoughts on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917209/setting-a-dynamic-hostname-on-aws-using-userdata