# Setting a dynamic hostname on AWS using UserData

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a bit of a chicken and egg problem.  I would like to set the Hostname during instance launch using `UserData`, but I need it to be an incremental one, such as

```
myapp01.us-west-2c.company.com
myapp02.us-west-2c.company.com
```

The `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration` can do this I believe for the `key/tag` pairs for `Name`.  However, how can I get `UserData` to do something similar?

Comment: Did you find a solution?